# Get the logged username according to the loggedtime using php?

Tags: php, arrays

> o/p:Here am getting the username,logged time and date

```
 Array
( [cena] => Array
        (
            [CentaurOne] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 29/12/17 01:02:15
                    [1] => 13/01/18 09:23:21
                )

            [count] => 2
        )

    [Bhumi] => Array
        (
            [CentaurOne] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 29/12/17 01:21:30
                    [1] => 29/12/17 09:23:11
                )

            [count] => 2
        )

    [John] => Array
        (
            [CentaurOne] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16/01/18 09:24:01
                    [1] => 18/01/18 02:51:20
                    [2] => 18/01/18 01:02:04
                    [3] => 19/01/18 01:02:04
                )

            [count] => 3
        )

)
```

Now i needed to get the username according to the users logged in time like given below:
cena 29/12/17 01:02:15
John 18/01/18 01:02:04 ,19/01/18 01:02:04

Comment: Have you attempted anything? :)

Comment: It would be much easier for people to provide you a solution if you can post a JSON encoded array rather than the contents of `var_dump`

Comment: Why `John 18/01/18 01:02:04 ,19/01/18 01:02:04`? what is logic behind that?.Also what you tried so far to overcome your ptoblem

Comment: This is my logfile details here i want to know particular time how is logged in Example : time-1.02 (How is logged in )

Comment: I use foreach loop I am getting error.  foreach ($Array as $srch)
    {
    $key = array_search ("01.02", srch);
    echo $key;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
$time = ' 01:02'; // note the begining space 
// or use : $time = '01:02:';
$matches = [] ;
foreach ($logs as $login => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $name => $dates) {
        if (! is_array($dates)) continue ; // avoid search in 'count'
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            if (strpos($date, $time) !== false) {
                $matches[$login][] = $date ;
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($matches) ;
```

Comment: i used ur code like this but i am getting invalid argument supplied for the foreach warning.Please help me.
  $time = '01:02'; // note the begining space 
// or use : $time = '01:02:';
$matches = [] ;
foreach ($abc as $login => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $name => $dates) {
        if (! is_array($dates)) continue ; // avoid search in 'count'
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            if (strpos($date, $time) !== false) {
                $matches[$login][] = $date ;
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($matches) ;

Comment: I got a answer thank you so much for the answer